# Creating a string from the keys and values of a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I need to make a list of strings from a dictionary in which the strings are the key, value pairs from the dictionary, sorted by the value of the pair.  For example, if these are my key,value pairs:

```
d = {'AAA': [0, 0, 1], 'BBB': [0, 1, 0], 'CCC': [0, 0, 1], 'DDD': [3, 1, 0]}
```

I need to return:

```
["DDD 3 1 0", "BBB 0 1 0", "AAA 0 0 1", "CCC 0 0 1"]
```

Note that if the values are the same, it is sorted alphabetically as well.  Any suggestions on how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Iterate over the key/value pairs; construct a string from the keys and values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort the dictionary in decreasing order by the value:

```
>>> sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

and then format the items "per spec" in a list comprehension:

```
>>> ['{k} {v[0]} {v[1]} {v[2]}'.format(k=k, v=v) for k, v in sorted_d]
['DDD 3 1 0', 'BBB 0 1 0', 'AAA 0 0 1', 'CCC 0 0 1']
```

I actually missed the requirement that in case of equal values you want to sort by the key (that just happened by accident - dictionaries are unordered). There are several ways to solve that:

- First sort by the key (not reverse) and then by the value (reverse):

  ```
  >>> from operator import itemgetter
  >>> sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(0))
  >>> sorted_d = sorted(sorted_d, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
  >>> ['{k} {v[0]} {v[1]} {v[2]}'.format(k=k, v=v) for k, v in sorted_d]
  ['DDD 3 1 0', 'BBB 0 1 0', 'AAA 0 0 1', 'CCC 0 0 1']
  ```
- Or create a custom class that compares exactly like you need it:

  ```
  class Compare(object):
      def __init__(self, key_value_pair):
          self.data = key_value_pair

      def __lt__(self, other):
          key1, value1 = self.data
          key2, value2 = other.data
          if value1 == value2:
              return key1 < key2
          else:
              return value1 > value2
  ```

  The rest stays roughly the same, except for the `reverse=True` part that was baked into the comparator:

  ```
  >>> sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=Compare)
  >>> ['{k} {v[0]} {v[1]} {v[2]}'.format(k=k, v=v) for k, v in sorted_d]
  ['DDD 3 1 0', 'BBB 0 1 0', 'AAA 0 0 1', 'CCC 0 0 1']
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

`sorted(["%s %s" % (k, ' '.join(map(str, v))) for k, v in d.items()])`

Edit:

If I understand your sort requirement:

`sorted(["%s %s" % (k, ' '.join(map(str, v))) for k, v in d.items()], key=lambda x: x.split(' ')[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: this is very helpful, but how can i sort it by the first number of the value in the dictionary?

Comment: Okay it's closer, although I should have clarified that it has to be sorted so that the first largest number is first, and if that number is a tie, sort by the next number, and if that one is a tie, sort by the next number.  So for example if its "AAA 1 0 0", "CCC 0 1 0", "BBB 0 1 0", "DDD 0 0 1", it has to come out as ["AAA 1 0 0",  "CCC 0 1 0", "BBB 0 1 0", "DDD 0 0 1"]

Comment: @ari.montario I believe your question is answered as per above. You shouldn't keep adding requirements to your question. I'd suggest asking another question, if you have further requirements. This is advantageous for you and an potential answerer as more rep points are on offer and you arent dragging the answerer into a question and answer session, which is bound to get you down voted.

Comment: @Jack you might get better performance and cleaner code if you do the sort on the result of `d.items()`. e.g. `["%s %s" % (k, ' '.join(map(str, v))) for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: v[1][0])]`. It would avoid the need for the ugly split operation.